# Ionic 5: How to save app changes after app has been closed?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm currently at a stage, in which I have an apk for my Ionic app. However, I noticed that when I'm interacting with app the and then close it, it would delete all the interactions/changes and the next start is just as I started the app for the first time.

Does anyone know the solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Redux**](https://redux.js.org/) is a *state manager* library. Most of the time you'll need to keep track of the changes of the application. So we use *Redux* to make it easier for the app developer. This can be hard to do without *Redux* in large scale systems.If you want to just **save data**, Ionic Framework comes with a *native plugin* called [Native Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage). If you want  the storage to be used in *Web* also. With [Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/storage) library it will work just fine.

The links provided are for apps built with Ionic Framework using **Cordova** as the API Layer. They need proper configuration before use.